# Find reason for building in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build, makefile

I'm using the devenv command line to build a quite large project. Sometimes it happens that some depends aren't set up correctly and cause a continuous build. It's quite difficult to find the real cause of the issue.
I'm looking for a devenv option, which tells me why a target needs to be built. Any ideas?

On Linux i'm using the GNU make tool and it has the option '--dry-run' and i'm looking for a similar option for devenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use MSBuild instead of devenv. It is too much faster and does not load the GUI for building your project. I also propose you to consider the dependencies one by one in your build script instead of building your fat solution directly.

Answer (score 2):

[Dependency Visualizer](http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/) provides a graphical representation of your project dependencies based on Visual Studio solution and project files.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's a great help to get an overview of the project depends. But for my problem it does not help, because i need to find the file which causes a project to build again.